# Importing Nodes to D7 with all custom fields

Tags: 7, nodes, importing-exporting

I've got a Drupal site with an obscene about of content that has been given to me in CSV format. I'm toying with the idea of building a module to let me do this but if there's one already out there that I can use to just get this site out of the way that would be awesome.

My question is: Is there anything out there that allows you to import a CSV file into D7 that will populate the node table and all the custom fields tables as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) (sucessor to the [FeedAPI module](http://drupal.org/project/feedapi)) has that functionality built in.

For your needs specifically it offers:

- Import or aggregate CSV files
- Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from import
- Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements